# Slide images every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my slideshow's images:

```
<section id="mainFooter">
            <div class="mainFooter">
                <p class="margRight">Jaafari Housseine &copy; 2013 <span>|</span> <a href="#!/page_privacy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
                <nav class="bgNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="images/picture1.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture2.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture3.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture4.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture5.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture6.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture7.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture8.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/picture9.jpg"><img src="images/pagination_act.png" alt="" class="img_act"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <p class="fright text"><img src="images/envelope.png" alt="" class="envelope">Résidence Harmonie N°19, Boulevard Abdelkarim Khattabi</p>
            </div>  
</section>
```

The jQuery script I used for that:

```
<script>
    $('ul li.active')(function(){$(this).removeClass("active")
        .delay(4500)
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).next('li').addClass("active");
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Nothing goes alright.

Comment: Hello Jeffery! Welcome to stack overflow. If you could go to http://www.jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io and create a small fiddle illustrating your problem instead of dumping a big piece of code, that would be great!

Comment: You should start by fixing the syntax errors displayed in your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to cycle which `<li>` tag has the "active" class on it and your CSS takes care of the rest, then you can do that like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var items = $("nav.bgNav ul li");
        var index = -1;

        function next() {
            // if not the very first iteration, 
            // remove the active class from prev item
            if (index !== -1) {
                items.eq(index).removeClass("active");
            }
            // go to next item
            ++index;
            // if past end, wrap to beginning
            if (index >= items.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            // add active class to next item
            items.eq(index).addClass("active");

            // schedule next iteration
            setTimeout(next, 4500);
        }

        next();
    });
</script>
```

Since your code only works on the active class, this solution assumes you have CSS that makes an image appear when the active class is on it and not appear when there is no active class and handles any transitions you want between images.  If you don't have that, then you will need it and you will have to disclose the rest of the relevant page HTML/CSS.  The "active" class is not magic.  It only does something when combined with CSS.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UnuCL/

---

Based on new understanding of what you're trying to do, here's a new piece of code that changes the actual img.src to the href of the containing  tag.  It cycles through each item by default.  When the mouse hovers over any given item, the cycling stops and that item displays it's new image.  When the mouse leaves that item, it restores that image and then the cycling starts again.  You can hover to stop and display that item, stop hovering to start the automatic cycling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // save original image URL for each
    var items = $("nav.bgNav ul li img");
    items.each(function() {
        $(this).data("orig-src", this.src);
    });

    var index = -1;
    var timer;

    function stop() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    function restore(i) {
        var oldItem;
        // if not the very first iteration, 
        // remove the active class from prev item
        if (i !== -1) {
            oldItem = items.eq(i);
            oldItem.closest("a").removeClass("active");
            oldItem.attr("src", oldItem.data("orig-src"));
        }
    }

    function display(i) {
        var newItem = items.eq(i);
        // change image .src based on parent <a> href
        newItem.attr("src", newItem.closest("a").attr("href"));

    }

    function next() {
        // restore currently active item
        restore(index);

        // go to next item
        ++index;
        // if past end, wrap to beginning
        if (index >= items.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        display(index);

        // schedule next iteration
        timer = setTimeout(next, 1000);
    }

    next();

    // now make hover do the same thing
    $("nav.bgNav ul li img").hover(function() {
        var hoverIndex = $(this).closest("li").index();
        stop();
        restore(index);
        display(hoverIndex);        
    }, function() {
        var hoverIndex = $(this).closest("li").index();
        index = hoverIndex;
        next();
    })

    $("nav.bgNav ul li a").click(function() {
        // ignore clicks
        return false;
    });

});
```

Full working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ux2Cg/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the images still not changing.

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati - see the notes I added to the end of my answer.  The "active" class is not magic - it's just a class name.  You have to have CSS that makes only the active `<li>` tag be visible.  Do you have such CSS?  Post a jsFiddle of your HTML, CSS and scripts and we can see the whole problem, not just what you have disclosed so far.

Comment: the css i made for that: .bgNav a:hover, .bgNav .active a {
 background-position: left center;
 background: url("../images/pagination_act.png") no-repeat;
}

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati - please put the CSS in your question (use the Edit link to modify your question).  All forms of code are difficult to read in comments.

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati - then, once you apply this code, the remaining problem is probably in your HTML/CSS.   Please make a jsFiddle that we can work on to see your entire issue.

Comment: sorry i'm new here so i don't know how to use the jsfiddel, but here it is the fiddle i saved: http://jsfiddle.net/hgPsA/

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati - by making the image URLs work in your jsFiddle, here's a working jsFiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UnuCL/

Comment: yes the class of each <LI> change but the images inside the <LI> doesn't change

Comment: Did you study the jsFiddle I posted?  Your CSS changes the background image only (not the main image) when the `.active` class is added.  There is no way to change the main image via a CSS and a class.  So that you could see the effect, I added CSS to hide the main image when the `.active` class is added, because I don't know what behavior you're actually trying to create (you don't describe it in your question).  The #1 requirement for a good question is that you very clearly state what you're trying to accomplish.  What exactly do you want to have happen to the target image at each change?

Comment: great, all i want is to change the image src inside the <a> tag, cause i used to click on each link to show the image, but what i want is to do it without clicking, if just i got ur email or something so i can send you all the files i have a jQuery file where i'm using to change the image after a click, but even if i'm changing it, it don't work as i want, sometimes the image change one time but the animation just stop i don't really know why, if it is possible to send you all the files so you can see where is the problem, thank you a lot and sorry.

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati - I put a whole new version of code into my answer.  You should be able to adapt this to whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thank you a lot brother for helping me, and i'm sorry bout disturbing you ^^

Comment: hi again, i have add this div where i put the src of the picture so i have to change the img src with the one in each link below in the section tag. the link where i added the new div tag: http://jsfiddle.net/UnuCL/12/

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati - I don't understand your question.  On what event do you want exactly what to happen?

Comment: i have added another tag where to show the images, so what i need is to change the source of the image after every 5sec, that's all, how do i can change the 'src' in jQuery, and thank you lot

Comment: Look in the `display()` function in my code and see where the existing code changes an `img.src` property.  That's how you do it in jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

There are many things out there that already do this, it may be easier for you to use one of those. Bootstrap has one, [here is a link to it](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel).

It's usage is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, "Using external library X" for doing something that is doable easily and natively is never considered a good solution to an SO question.

Comment: While it is something that can be done natively, external libraries tend to provide stability for edge cases that arise, such as multiple slideshows (which the above solution wouldn't provide). As well, as the OP seems relatively new to web design, introducing him to a library which can be extremely useful seemed like a nice thing to do.

Comment: I'm sure it is, however, it has been discussed in meta several times, and it was decided that users should not put answers that say 'use this library' unless the OP asked for it himself. For example, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question . It would also fit as a nice comment

Comment: Thanks for the link. I dont however (along with a majority of the user base of stackoverflow im sure) keep up with meta. I'm also not quite sure what you mean by 'It would also fit as a nice comment'.

Comment: While as an answer your answer is problematic, it could serve as a nice comment. It is commenting on the question, telling users what else could be done. It does not directly answer the question itself